# Cascade configuration settings to main application appsettings.json

Tags: .net, json, configuration, application-settings

I have a .Net Core 2.2 website with an appsettings.json file which happily serves settings within the website. The website makes use of a nuget mail merging package which requires its own appsettings.json. When I try to run the website and call a page which makes use of the mail merging package, an error is thrown because the mail merging package cannot find its own appsettings.json.

Is there a way of making the mail merging package read from the website's appsettings.json?

My website's configuration is set up in the following way:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
           Services.Configure<AppSettings>Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        }
}
```

The appsettings.json file is structured like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Variable to be overridden by user secrets or within CI pipeline- do not use this file"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      //"Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AppSettings": {
    "PageSize": "10"
  },
  "MailMerge": {
    "MaximumOutputFileSize": 100000000,
    "MaximumInMemoryBufferSize": 10000000
  }
}
```

The "MailMerge" section is the one I'd hoped would be used by the mail merging package.

Comment: Have you tried loading the configuration manually instead of injecting it into startup?

Comment: What is the mail package looking for? are you sure you are adding it correctly to your settings?

Comment: Does the mail merge package have documentation about where the setting should be?